# "Can't iterate over integer" when trying to do a list operation in Python

Tags: python, list, typeerror

I am trying to code something in Python. I get an error that I can't iterate over an integer when I try to use the list() command to turn a string into a list of characters but only after it has already been done 6 times. My code:

```
#Datenleser und Schreiber
datei = open('werte.txt','r')
linelist = datei.readlines()
lastline = len(linelist)-1
resultlist = linelist.copy()
nonlength = 0
biggest = 0
#Funktion, die Zahlen aus einer Liste Physikalischer Größen mit trennendem Leerzeichen filtert
def stringconvert(liste):
    templist = [0]
    for i in range(len(liste)):
        templist.clear()
        templist = list(liste[i])
        delcount = 0
        delnow = False
        tempe = [0]
        tempval = 0
        esolver = 0
        hase = False
        for x in range(len(templist)):
            if templist[x-delcount] == " ":
                del templist[x]
                delcount = delcount + 1
                delnow = True
            elif delnow == True:
                del templist[x-delcount]
                delcount = delcount + 1
        for x in range(len(templist)):
            if templist[x] == "e":
                tempe.clear()
                hase = True
                for i in range(x):
                    tempe.append(templist[i])
                    tempval = float("".join(tempe))
                tempe.clear()
                for l in range(len(templist)-x):
                    try:
                        tempe.append(templist[x+1+l])
                    except:
                        lol = 3
                esolver = 10**float("".join(tempe))
                print(tempval,esolver)
        if hase == False:
            liste[i] = "".join(templist)
        else:
            liste[i] = int(tempval*esolver)
stringconvert(resultlist)
for i in range(len(linelist)):
    if "mm" in linelist[i]:
        print(resultlist[i-nonlength])
        resultlist[i-nonlength] = float(resultlist[i-nonlength])/1000
    if "cm" in linelist[i]:
        resultlist[i-nonlength] = float(resultlist[i-nonlength])/100
    if "dm" in linelist[i]:
        resultlist[i-nonlength] = float(resultlist[i-nonlength])/10
    if "yd" in linelist[i]:
        resultlist[i-nonlength] = float(resultlist[i-nonlength])*0.9144
    else:
        if (" m\n" in linelist[i]) == False:
            del resultlist[i-nonlength]
            nonlength = nonlength + 1
for i in range(len(resultlist)):
    print(resultlist[i],"m")
```

The output and error I get:

```
10.566 10000000000.0
2.732 1000000.0

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[18], line 47
     45         else:
     46             liste[i] = int(tempval*esolver)
---> 47 stringconvert(resultlist)
     48 for i in range(len(linelist)):
     49     if "mm" in linelist[i]:

Cell In[18], line 13, in stringconvert(liste)
     11 for i in range(len(liste)):
     12     templist.clear()
---> 13     templist = list(liste[i])
     14     delcount = 0
     15     delnow = False

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

The content of the .txt file:

```
15.0 m
3.14 yd
5.345 s
10.566e10 g
2.732e6 mm
1.25 A
3.82e3 mC
5 cm
2.952321 kg
1.11111 H
```

As you can see, the code seems to work fine for the first few iterations of the big for loop of the stringconverter() method. However, when the code gets to working on line six of the werte.txt document containing "1.25 A", it suddenly breaks and I don't understand why. Probably some obscure python knowledge I don't have. The only things that has changed in relation to the previous lines is that a capital letter is included from what I can tell. Can someone please explain to me why this error is occuring?

Comment: Use a debugger to see at which moment in your program `liste[i]` is being assigned to an integer.

Comment: You're reusing the `i` variable for the nested loop while you still need the old value.

Comment: The error is telling you that it isn't a string.